# Toggle between showing and hiding an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, toggle, hide, visibility, show

I am working on toggling between showing and hiding an element when an icon is clicked.

**JS Function that toggles between showing and hiding the element**

```
function connectionShowHideToggle(element)
{
var clickedId =  element.id;
var elementID=clickedId = clickedId.charAt(0);
var ImportCon = elementID+"-import";
var ExportCon = elementID+"-export";
var DefinedCon = elementID+"-defined";

var importConExists = document.getElementById(ImportCon);
alert(importConExists);
var exportConExists = document.getElementById(ExportCon);
alert(exportConExists);
var definedConExists = document.getElementById(DefinedCon);
alert(definedConExists);

if(importConExists != null)
{
    if(importConExists+ $(':visible').length)
        $(importConExists).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    else
        $(importConExists).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);

}

else if(exportConExists != null) 
{
    if(exportConExists+ $(':visible').length)
        $(exportConExists).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    else
        $(exportConExists).visibility=true;
}

else if(definedConExists != null)
{
    if(definedConExists+ $(':visible').length)
        $(definedConExists).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    else
        $(definedConExists).visibility=true;
}
}
```

Neither of the code segments work

`$(importConExists).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);`

or

`$(importConExists).visibility=true;`

When the element is initially visible and this function is called, the icon is hidden but when I hide the element initially and then call this method, the element is **NOT** shown. Suggestions in this regard will be appreciated

Modified code:

[image: code]

The hide() works fine but the show() doesn't.

Comment: tried the jquery toggle() function?

Comment: jQuery has two functions to toggle: toggle and slideToggle. The selector for id is $('#' + elementID + '-import')

Comment: The thing is, since the hide function above works fine, the only issue is that the show() function is not being identified. I modified the code as `$(definedConExists).hide();` and `$(definedConExists).show();` . Here the hide is identified and works but the show doesn't. I'd like to have the same fixed and if it doesn't work I'll consider the toggle function